# How can I restore a backup in Opencart from command line? (no admin panel)

Tags: mysql, opencart

I`m stacked with a Opencart problem. After restoring and old backup, now I cannot login into the admin panel anymore. The problem was an installation of a language extension, then I deleted the default English language. The problem persisted so I tried to restore a backup, but that backup has the admin panel language set to English, now I see in the database only Español. I guess that is the reason of the login failure.

If restoring back to the previous state, I will be able to enter again, but I need the way to restore a backup without admin panel, using the database. O maybe a way to add English language to the oc_language table y de db...

```
MariaDB [opencartdb]> select * from oc_language;
+-------------+----------+------+-------------+-----------+------------+--------+
| language_id | name     | code | locale      | extension | sort_order | status |
+-------------+----------+------+-------------+-----------+------------+--------+
|           4 | Español  | es   | es_ES.UTF-8 |           |          1 |      1 |
+-------------+----------+------+-------------+-----------+------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.002 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... At first check language_id from `oc_product_description` table. And sure that English had 1 or other number.

You need to insert English Language

```
insert into `oc_language` set `name` = 'English', `code` = 'en-gb', `locale`= 'en.GB', `extension`='',  `sort_order` = '2', `status`= '1';
```

After that command you must update language_id:

```
update `oc_language` set `language_id`= 1 where `code` = 'en-gb';
```